# I am not allowed by you to post images but my reputation is over 300.

Tags: support, images, privileges

Hi: I have posted a post in math dot stackexcange dot com which includes an image and your site said that I could not post and image because I should have reputation above 10 to do that. But according to you my reputation was above 300 at the moment I posted.

So, I want to post another image to see if the error (in case it is an error) repeats itself. Can I post a test post in math dot meta dot stackexchange dot com? And in case I can what message should I include in the post so that other users do not complain?

Comment: It sounds to me like the system did not see you as logged in, perhaps because of a caching issue.  However you can still try posting an image by editing your post on the Main Math.SE site, and this would be more definitive.  If you get an error, take a screen shot and then post that image here with a link to the post involved.

Comment: Try logout followed by login.

Comment: @hardmath: "take a screen shot and then post that image here": but the site did not allow posting images I tell you. Oh! does not allow in math does not imply does not allow in math.meta?

Comment: @hardmath: "It sounds to me like the system did not see you as logged in, perhaps because of a caching issue": does it mean the problem was yours and not my system's?

Comment: Even if the system does not allow you to "post images" in quite the way you tried (which is not clearly detailed in your Question), you should be able to (1) upload the image to *imgur* (using the editing "picture" icon) so long as the image format (one of your unexplained details) is compatible, and (2) to include the imgur link in your post here or on Main Math.SE.  Without any quotation of the error message, it is merely a guess that the StackExchange site software didn't recognize *your* account being online (in your browser).  Are you connecting to Math.SE with a "shared computer?

Comment: No, I am not. I have been said, by math.stackexchange.com, several times I was not logged in when in fact I was. Next time I'll post the error message. Thanks for your posts. As to the images thing, all I am able to tell you is this: I was working within Xfce 4. The image was inside the clipboard, a thing of Xfce, I think (the PDF reader sent the image to the clipboard). And from the clipboard it went to the edit window of your site I was writing in. Oh, I'll try your procedure (imgur) next time I have an issue uploading images.